# Как изменять исходный код страницы на сервере?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Помогите, нужно изменять исходный код страницы так, чтобы после перезагрузки, показывалась уже обновленная страница. Как такое можно реализовать? В моем примере, чтобы после каждой перезагрузки счетчик увеличивался на 1, а не начинался заново с 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style>
      #plan { 
         display: inline-block;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
Загрузок: <div id="plan">0</div>
<script>
var plan = document.getElementById('plan');
$("#plan").empty();
document.getElementById('plan').innerHTML = plan.innerHTML + 1;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения состояния между перезагрузками можно использовать localStorage

```
var plan = document.getElementById('plan');
localStorage.loadCount = (localStorage.loadCount|0) + 1;
plan.innerText = localStorage.loadCount;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgb03xn5/)

---

```
<?php
$fn = 'counter.txt';
$count = file_exists($fn)?file_get_contents($fn):0;
file_put_contents($fn, ++$count);
?>
<div>
  <?=$count?>
</div>
```

Comment: Пока его не очистят вручную...

Comment: Это немного не то, нужно чтобы это сохранялось на сервере и информация была бы одинаковой откуда бы я ни зашел.

Comment: Извините, я не нашёл ни намёка на серверную часть в вашем вопросе(кроме тега php)... Существует 1001 способ сохранить счётчик на сервере.

Comment: До этого момента я надеялся, что это все можно сделать средствами JS.

Comment: Значение счетчика в любом случае надо куда-то сохранять - в БД, в текстовый файл или еще куда.